# how can I verify a spy is called with "null" param

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, spy

I'm trying to run this line:

```
verify(imagesSorterSpy, atLeast(2)).sortImages(anyList(), null);
```

to verify this method was called with null as second argument.

but i get this error:

```
rg.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

how can I verify invocation with null as 2nd arg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error indicates you cannot mix `raw` or `real` values with `matchers`.

Since i dont know the method `sortImages` signature, am going to guess

`sortImage(List, String)`.

If thats the case, the below should work.

`verify(imagesSorterSpy, atLeast(2)).sortImages(anyList(), isNull(String.class));`

`isNull` is from `org.mockito.Matchers.isNull`

Comment: In any case. It is worth mentioning that when using explicit matchers, they have to be used for all arguments of the stub.

Comment: how can I limit the anyList() to non-empty lists or a list which is greater than 2 ?